Vocalist of Miss You produced by Oliver Tree & Robin Schulz
I am on a search of who did vocals for this music video: 

 I am looking through the credits and it surprises me a lot not to find any female singers there. Or am I simply missing sth obvious?

Not a sound engineer here, but I'm pretty sure it has been sung by Oliver Tree himself.
Start points:

Copyright stuff mentioning Marshmello, Oliver Tree Nickell, and David Andrew Pramik as the writers (lyrics, vocals, instrumentals, all of that, not including performing); no any female here:

"Jerk", "Miss You" originated/remixed from
"Miss You"


Remix stuff:

"Miss You" samples;


Music stuff

"Jerk" is 160 BPM, A key (but D key for chorus; checked it using a guitar);
"Miss You" is 145 BPM, F# key;



What I did "Jerk" to sound like "Miss You":

using yt-dlp -x, downloaded the "Jerk" official lyrics video from YouTube;
using audio-separator (not a perfect AI-based vocals removal tool), removed the instrumental from the original audio (however, there seems to be a cleaner "Jerk" vocals rip-off);
in Audacity, trimmed the vocals audio tracks to the essential part, changed pitch up by four semitones from D to F# and changed the tempo down from 160 BPM to 145 BPM (~1.103448276 slower or ~0.90625 faster), not bothering with sox though.

Sounds (almost?) identical to "Miss You", and the article on Wikipedia claims that the Tree's vocals were re-recorded (I couldn't hear minor differences, though, having no professional equipment and environment).
What I did "Miss You" to sound like "Jerk":

downloaded the "Miss You" official audio from YouTube;
removed the instrumentals;
trimmed the audio, changed the pitch down by four semitones from F# to D and changed the tempo up from 145 BPM to 160 BPM (~1.103448276 faster or ~0.90625 slower).

Definitely, Tree's vocals.
Side note
I also found the first-best live performance video of "Miss You" and Tree sings the song in the original D key, not the "Miss You" remix F# key, "Jerk" was originally written in, and most likely Tree's vocals are best for.
Temporary audio make-up link
Oliver Tree - Jerk % Miss You
I'll delete the shared folder in a week or two.

@ terrorrussia-keeps-killing Thank you kind Sir or Madam. This is very insightful and - though I am not able to understand it all due to my musical illiteracy - I really appreciate the effort you have put into the analysis.

@MarekPuchalski No problem! Actually, I'm not a musician and I can play guitar just a little bit, but I'm kind of able to understand tempo, pitch, intervals, chords, or other basic theory stuff -- this is the highest point of my music "education". However, back to the subject, for long time I also believed that the "Miss You" vocals are female, and I was really surprised that changing the pitch of the song reveals Tree's vocals. This is why I also had to go through the music copyright database to make sure there were no persons to sing other than Tree. I'm really glad I could help you out!
